# RetryTemplate reinvokes RestTemplate, generating new request ID

Tags: java, spring, http

We have a HTTP PUT endpoint which mutates data. Sometimes, the requester fails to receive the response, upon which he may resend the request. However, the request may have succeeded on the recipient's side, causing a second data-mutating request to be processed again. This is easily fixed with a request ID in the request header which remains the same between all retries of the request, such that the recipient can filter them out, and even remap the old response to the new request.

The problem we are facing is that `RetryTemplate` reinvokes `RestTemplate`, causing a completely different request ID to be generated for every retry of a request.

```java
@Bean
public RestTemplate defaultRestTemplate(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory defaultHttpClientRequestFactory) {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .requestFactory(() -> defaultHttpClientRequestFactory)
            .additionalRequestCustomizers(
                    request -> request.getHeaders().set(RequestConstants.HEADER_CLIENT_REQUEST_ID, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            )
            .build();
}
```

This is sort of by design of `RetryTemplate`, so we wonder what is the DRY (i.e. don't write our own wrapper method) way to get the desired behavior?

Ideally, the following test code would pass:

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class DefaultHttpRetryTemplateConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    protected RestTemplate defaultRestTemplate;

    @Autowired
    protected RetryTemplate defaultHttpRetryTemplate;

    @Test
    void defaultHttpRetryTemplate_providesSameRequestIdInRetryRequests_butDifferentRequestIdsInOriginalRequests() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        String[] requestIds = new String[2];
        Future<String> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            return testRequest();
        });
        requestIds[0] = testRequest();
        requestIds[1] = future.get();
        Assert.assertNotEquals(requestIds[0], requestIds[1]); // Different request ID in different original requests.
    }

    private String testRequest() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try (MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer()) {
            mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(500));
            mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200));
            mockWebServer.start();

            HttpUrl url = mockWebServer.url("/test");

            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("{}");
            this.defaultHttpRetryTemplate.execute(retryCallback -> {
                return this.defaultRestTemplate.exchange(url.uri(), HttpMethod.PUT, entity, String.class);
            });

            RecordedRequest[] requests = new RecordedRequest[2];
            requests[0] = mockWebServer.takeRequest();
            requests[1] = mockWebServer.takeRequest();

            String[] uuids = new String[2];
            uuids[0] = requests[0].getHeader(RequestConstants.HEADER_CLIENT_REQUEST_ID);
            uuids[1] = requests[1].getHeader(RequestConstants.HEADER_CLIENT_REQUEST_ID);

            Assert.assertEquals(uuids[0], uuids[1]); // Same request ID in retries.
            return uuids[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will not work due to request customizer called every time before request is gone away. So, on each retry it will generate new. The most simple and proper way is to set it up explicitly with `HttpEntity` in the headers object. It will guarantee that the same header will be reused on each retry. If you want to keep auto-generation inside customizer - you can add check: if request already contains this header - just do nothing, otherwise put auto-generated.

Going this way, you can achieve required behavior and still have ability to implicitly generate `requestid` inside customizer.

NOTE: Otherwise, you will need to keep the generated id somewhere like ThreadLocal context, to be able to restore it. Definitely, I do not recommend to go this way.

Comment: We ended up going with a static `HttpHeaders` factory method and using `addIfAbsent()` in the customizer.

Comment: Great, that I was able to help you!